# Permutation problem on rearranging players

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

[image]

I'm stuck on this problem. At first, I thought the solution will be;

$$11! - (3! \cdot 8! \cdot 9)$$

However, when I checked, the answer was completely different. Any suggestions for how I might approach it?

Thanks.

Comment: You've simply misread the problem. You (correctly) counted the number of orders in which Adam, Brad, and Chris do not stand as a single consecutive block of three people. The problem asks for the number of orders in which *no two of* Adam, Brad, and Chris are next to each other.

Comment: Please do not post an image in your question when text, maybe with the addition of MathJax, will do as well.  Text in an image cannot be found by search engines, which hampers readers in the future who may be searching for something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you interpreted the problem to mean that Adam, Brad, and Chris could not be in consecutive positions.  However, the problem asks you to find the number of arrangements in which no two of those three team members are adjacent.

Have Adam, Brad, and Chris wait while the other eight team members form a line.  This creates nine spaces, seven between successive team members and two at the ends of the row, where Adam, Brad, and Chris could be placed.
$$\square p_1 \square p_2 \square p_3 \square p_4 \square p_5 \square p_6 \square p_7 \square p_8 \square$$
To ensure that no two of Adam, Brad, and Chris are consecutive, choose three of these nine spaces in which to place the three of them.  Then arrange Adam, Brad, and Chris in the selected spaces.